# Supporting this old 2x4 hip roof rafter to the beam

Tags: joists, support, hanger

I'm renovating an old house which had a hip roof. One of the roof rafters (2x4) comes down on an angle and isn't supported on the beam. I thought a strong tie lssj would work but the rafter is a bit too high.

What kind of hanger / tie could I use to support the rafter on the beam?

[image]

Comment: The rafter was cut by someone during the modification. Restore it, it is required to be fastened to the beam, not hanging around.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal is a 3-4' scab with the appropriate hip/valley plumb cut and a 45 miter sistered onto the hip rafter and fastened to the beam.

The reality is that almost anything will do--hips usually don't carry much weight and are almost self-supporting, just as a ridge board often is.